# Turn off prompting for executing shell links in org mode

Tags: org-mode

If I add the following to an org-mode file:

```
[[shell:DIR]]
```

It creates a link which will run 'DIR' and show the output in a separate window.

Here's the result:

[image]

Now, right after you open the link, you are prompted about running the command:

[image]

I'm working with an org-file that I created and thus I trust the commands in it. Is there a way to turn off this prompting?

Comment: See https://orgmode.org/manual/Code-evaluation-security.html

Comment: Aha! Looks like that should do the trick. Thanks @JohnKitchin!

Comment: the link to the manual page given by @JohnKitchin has changed to:
https://orgmode.org/manual/Code-Evaluation-Security.html